# The local time doesn't change when i change the city in my app. I used luxon library for dates and times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, luxon

I have been doing a weather app, all the stuff are working, but the time for any city is the same as my local time.

I have checked the code many times, but without answers

My code:

weatherService.js :

```
const formatToLocalTime = (secs, zone, format = "cccc, dd LLL yyyy' | Local time: 'hh:mm a") => DateTime
    .fromSeconds(secs)
    .setZone(zone)
    .toFormat(format)

const iconUrlFromCode = (code) => `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${code}@2x.png`

export default getFormattedWeatherData;

export { formatToLocalTime, iconUrlFromCode };
```

part of App.js im interesting:

```
<TimeLocation weather={weather} />
```

TimeLocation.jsx :

```
import React from 'react'
import { formatToLocalTime } from '../services/weatherServices'

const TimeLocation = ({ weather: { dt, timezone, name, country } }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="flex items-center justify-center my-6">

                <p className=" text-white text-xl font-extralight">{formatToLocalTime(dt, timezone)}</p>
            </div>


            <div className="flex items-center justify-center my-3">
                <p className='text-white text-3xl font-medium'>{`${name}, ${country} `}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TimeLocation
```

appreciate your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your code properly. It's very difficult to read as it stands. [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002) which you may find useful.

Comment: you can use moment.js as it is pretty straightforward

Comment: @Vijay momentjs is deprecated no longer maintained and no longer do the authors recommend use of it.  They have other methods that they suggested on their site even.